# Переключение и включение/выключение активных классов jquery

Tags: jquery, классы

Добрый день.

Вот мой [вариант](https://jsfiddle.net/ak1sr4ds/25/)

```
$('.smal_cart h6').on( "click", function() {
$('.smal_cart h6').parent().parent().removeClass('cart_active');
$(this).parent().parent().addClass('cart_active'); });
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, как помимо переключения активного класса у родителя, при клике на элемент активного родителя, этот активный класс снимался?

Спасибо.

Comment: Возможно поможет пример логики работы, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/760837/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-toggleclass/760848

Comment: Я облегчил вариант - https://jsfiddle.net/ak1sr4ds/17/, теперь вопрос в просто отключении класса при повторном клике на активный, помимо переключения.

Answer (score 0):

[Получилось.](https://jsfiddle.net/ak1sr4ds/41/)

```
$('.smal_cart h6').on( 'click', function(){
    var parent = $(this).parent().parent();
    if( $(parent).hasClass('cart_active')){
                    $('.smal_cart h6').parent().parent().removeClass('cart_active');
            } else {
        $('.smal_cart h6').parent().parent().removeClass('cart_active');
        $(parent).addClass('cart_active');
    } });
```